# trying to get property of non-objec error

Tags: php

lets see code

```
public function chekfactor( $factor,$user) {    
               $arrfactor=preg_split('/<td>/',$factor);
                  $arrusers=preg_split('/<td>/',$user);
             $tedstore=count($arrusers) ;
              $tedkala=count($arrfactor) ;
               $inttedstore=(int) $tedstore;
 $inttedkala=(int)$tedkala;
$afa="0";
$a=(int)$afa;
 for (;$a<$inttedstore;){
  $storeusername=$arrusers[$a];
      $faktorss=$arrfactor[$a];
  $tablename='devlist'.$storeusername;
  echo   $tablename;
      echo   $faktorss;
           $result = $this->conn->query("SELECT id FROM'".$tablename."' WHERE prcode='".$faktorss."' ");

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    $user = array();
                    $user[$faktorss] = $row["id"];


              return $user;
            }
        }else {

             return "no";
        }


  $a++;
}
```

and give to me the errors

> trying to get property of non-object on line 543 means "  if
>   ($result->num_rows > 0) { "

why happen and how fix it ?

Comment: that means you don't have result in `$result` add `if` condition to check it has value or not

Comment: Your query syntax is off. You have quotes around the tablename, and no space between `FROM` and the tablename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess your query is not working because of your quotes and space

```
"SELECT id FROM'".$tablename."' WHERE prcode='".$faktorss."'";
```

query will print like

```
SELECT id FROM'table_1' WHERE..
```

you can change like

```
"SELECT id FROM ".$tablename." WHERE prcode=".$faktorss."";
```

Answer (score 2):

change the line

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
```

for

```
if (!empty($result)) // make sure it is having value then use `num_rows` on it
```

The issue is that you are trying to access to num_rows property when `$result` is empty.

Comment: It is better to use `isset` or `empty` instead of just an `if`.

Comment: The value will always be set, it will either be an object or `false` - so checking on the variable directly is fine as this code is structured.

Comment: I think that always where is possible we should use IF in a positive way, for to improve the reading. To use "if ($result)" is completely valid in a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if($result && !empty($result)){
   $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
   if($num_rows > 0){
     //the logic here
   }
}
```

Comment: it will throw the same error as OP mentioned , problem is $result is empty so you can not access `num_rows` on it